# Ubuntu 18.04 Laptop keeps on getting print screen

Tags: 18.04, print-screen

Laptop keeps on getting print screens and saving to picture folder at random key presses. (e.g. Ctrl+c, space bar, esc,back space, Enter and even when press numeric buttons etc).
pls help.

Comment: This would be good to try to use a different OS, either Windows or Ubuntu installer USB.  I am thinking that it is a hardware problem in that your keyboard is wonky.  Can you try an external keyboard?

Comment: Clean your keyboard carefully, especially around the PrintScr key.